# how to watch an array in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Trying to watch an array ('CurrentDetails'). But the data is empty inside the watch function, after updating it. where am i going wrong here.

**myctrl.js:**

```
 app.controller("myctrl", function ($scope, SharedService) {
       $scope.CurrentDetails = [];

      var init = function(){
      var data = {
                OptionsType: "LanguageOptions",
                OptionItems: [{ "OptionId": 1, "OptionName": "English"}],
                Breadcrumbs: ["Home"]
            }                
            $scope.ShowResponse(data);
     }
     $scope.ShowResponse = function (data) {
        $scope.CurrentDetails = data;  
        console.log($scope.CurrentDetails); //can see the data here
     }

       $scope.$watch('CurrentDetails', function () {
        console.log($scope.CurrentDetails); //no data here 
        SharedService.updateCurrentDetails($scope.CurrentDetails);
      },true);
       $scope.$on('valuesUpdated', function () {        
          $scope.CurrentDetails = SharedService.CurrentDetails;        
      });

       init();
    }
```

**sharedservice.js:**

```
app.service("SharedService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
 var service = {};
 service.CurrentDetails = [];
 service.updateCurrentDetails = function (value) {
        this.CurrentDetails = value;
        $rootScope.$broadcast("valuesUpdated");
    }

}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13977/

Comment: There's `$watchCollection` to watch for changes in the array

Comment: try `$scope.$watch('CurrentDetails', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log(newVal); 
        SharedService.updateCurrentDetails(newVal);
      },true);` it should work

Comment: @pankajparkar; It's empty for both new&old Values

Comment: @NewDev.Tried with $watchCollection. I see empty [] in the console, still

Answer (score 2):

trigger the `init` function at the end of the controller.

Anonymous functions referenced by variables will be initialized lazily.

For more details [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Watch is fired with the values, Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13979/

Comment: @Vinay.Other than the console.log, could you please tell me the other changes made. I still get empty arrays [] [] in code

Comment: declared the module `ng-app="myApp"` in the markup.

Comment: @VinayK +1 Good catch. you played with variables :p